# ctrl-w stops vim on CentOS

Tags: linux, vim, centos

I just tried running Vi IMproved 7.2 on CentOS 6.5.

The command <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> which normally allows screen splitting and navigation is stopping VIM, and going back to terminal, leaving VIM as a stopped process (.vimrc is empty).

I tried remapping  in .vimrc but it still closes VIM.

I also tried creating a shortcut key (System/Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> doing nothing. Then the shortcut doesn't close VIM anymore but it does nothing and cannot be used in VIM neither.

How could I disable this stopping functionality on CentOS ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See if it's mapped to something else with `:verbose map <C-w>`.

Comment: I use vim 7.2.411 on CentOS 6.5, but it works. Which terminal do you used ?

Comment: @romainl : No it's not, I get "No mapping found". Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brightshine : it's GNOME Terminal 2.31.3. I tested the same version of VI on my colleague's CentOS 6.5, it works fine as well. Yet we installed CentOS from the same .iso file (it's a virtual machine).

Comment: The letter `z` is placed at the key `w` on some keyboards (french one). Can you do `Control-V + Control-Z` and give us the output ?

Comment: what's the best way to narrow the interpretation of the terminal vs. the os vs. vim?